# Nspredicate format for greater than 8 in swift

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I am trying to sort array using NSPredicate using NSPredicate format

```
"(value IN { '1','2','5', $LOWER })"
```

but I want to get value grater than 8 and use

```
"(value >='7')"
```

It sort value upto 9 ,but not able to sort value equal or greater than 10. I also try between , OR ,AND operator but its not working .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using string compare instead of number, that's why '10' is less than '9'. It's because of the quotes.

So I think the right format would be (when the `value` property is number):

```
"(value >= 7)"
```

Comment: what do you mean it's not working? Maybe I didn't understand the whole problem. What does the first format do? And what's `$LOWER` ?

Comment: let resultPredicate2 = NSPredicate(format:"(value IN { '5', $LOWER })", argumentArray: nil)
                
               let searchResultsFor2 = (tableListArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate2.predicateWithSubstitutionVariables(["LOWER": "6"])) as AnyObject!).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
here tablelistarray  is main array .this method is used to predicate 5,6 value from array, for value greater than 8 ,resultPredicate2 = NSPredicate(format:"( value => $LOWER )", argumentArray: nil),where $LOWER = 7,

Comment: this doesn't make much sense. But if you are using swift, I would use `filter` method instead of predicate and you can define anything in the block. Like this:

`let results = tableListArray.filter { $0.value > 7 }`